# How do you make remain the sum of three numbers the same if you have to change one and only one of the members?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've found this example in a textbook (text may be subject to change since I translated it).
Following equality is given:

```
18+17+5=40
```

How do you change only one member of the leften side so the sum remains the same? I might be the stupidest person ever but I really don't get it...

Comment: $15+17+8=40$ and it is not equality at all

Comment: It's impossible, if you change only one element then the sum will change. You need to change at least two elements (make some larger and some smaller=

Comment: And how am I wrong?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling yes, this is what I don't get and it's not the first time this book tells change one whatever and you just can't...

Comment: My guess is that this is some sort of trick question. Obviously none of x,y,z in x + y + z  can be unilaterally changed without changing the sum. Some sort of playing around with symbols is intended, perhaps changing an operator rather than a number. If so, I don't see it.

Comment: Maybe it is a trick question.

Comment: Well, this book is for kids aged 11...

Comment: I guess it really depends on how much we are allowed to change.

Comment: But then 'change two' is also listed.

Comment: How is the problem stated in the book?

Comment: Perhaps an 11 year old would accept 18 + 17 + 05 = 40 as a solution, with 5 being "changed" to 05.

Comment: @uomoinverde somehow like this but I'm not really proing in English:
Let sum remain the same while:
a) you change one member
b) you change two member
c) you change three member

Answer (score 1):

If *member* has the meaning of "number", then you can play around with operations to get it done: for example,

$$
\begin{aligned}
18 + 17 + 5 &= 40 \\
18 - 17 + 39 &= 40.
\end{aligned}
$$

However, if operators cannot be modified, there's no way to change just one number keeping the relation true.

If you have an identity

$$
a + b + c = d
$$
and a number $\alpha$ such that, without loss of generality,

$$
\alpha + b + c = d,
$$

then you have

$$
\begin{cases}
a = d - (b + c) \\
\alpha = d - (b + c)
\end{cases}
\implies a = \alpha.
$$

---

As pointed out by John in a comment, it can be an interesting exercise to understand the power of positional notation: if you add one or more leading zeros to a number, its value won't change, thus

$$
00018 + 17 + 5 = 40
$$

still holds, for example.

Comment: is there a reason why the $39$ is there ?